# How to distinguish between invalid token and lack of permission in rest

Tags: rest, jwt

What is the standard way to respond so the client can distinguish if their token is invalid/revoked OR they just tried to access some resource they do not have authorization for ? Do both use 401? Should I use a custom body?

Comment: PS. Sorry, I am on mobile

Comment: That's often distinguished via 401 vs. 403 (though note this isn't specific to JWTs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an invalid or revoked token is basically the same as not having a token. This is typically indicated with the `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` [status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2). It means, we cannot establish who you are. (unauthorized should really have been unauthenticated)

The `HTTP 403 Forbidden` response means, we know who you are (you are authenticated), but you do not have permission to access the requested resource.